# How to send a xquery to a BaseX database via http

Tags: http, xquery, basex

I am trying to use the http interface to access a BaseX database.

The setup is as follows:

- installed the latest basex on my windows 10 system (version 10.7)
- created a user test with password test
- imported a simple xml:

```
`   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <musicCollection>
        <entry>
            <Type>CD</Type>
            <Name>Greatest Hits</Name>
            <Artist>The Music Band</Artist>
            <Year>1998</Year>
            <Songs>
                <Song>
                    <Name>Song 1</Name>
                    <Author>John Songwriter</Author>
                    <Length>4:30</Length>
                </Song>
                <Song>
                    <Name>Song 2</Name>
                    <Author>Lisa Lyricist</Author>
                    <Length>3:45</Length>
                </Song>
                <Song>
                    <Name>Song 3</Name>
                    <Author>Lisa Lyricist</Author>
                    <Length>1:45</Length>
                </Song>
            </Songs>
        </entry>
        .... more entries
    </musicCollection>
`
```

- checked the setup with the CLI interface:

java -cp BaseX.jar org.basex.BaseXClient
... login in as test / test ...

at the prompt:

```
xquery for $e in doc('music')/musicCollection/entry where $e/Type = "LP" return <entry> {$e/Type} {$e/Name} {$e/Artist} </entry>
```

Result:

```
<entry><Type>LP</Type><Name>Rock Revolution</Name><Artist>The Rockers</Artist></entry>
<entry><Type>LP</Type><Name>Rock Revolution</Name><Artist>The Other Ones</Artist></entry>
Query "BaseX" executed in 6.44 ms.
```

- then I started the http subsystem with the included script on port 123:

```
"D:\Programs\BaseX\bin\basexhttp.bat" -h123
```

- in another command shell I used curl to access the database:

```
curl -u test:test -X POST -d "for $e in doc('music')/musicCollection/entry return <entry> {$e/Type} {$e/Name} {$e/Artist} </entry>" "http://localhost:123/rest"
```

and this:

```
curl -u test:test -X POST -d "for $e in /musicCollection/entry return <entry> {$e/Type} {$e/Name} {$e/Artist} </entry>" "http://localhost:123/rest/music"
```

`
I got this error reply:

```
"" (Line 1): Content ist nicht zulässig in Prolog. (Line 1: content is illegal in prolog)
```

trying this:

```
curl -u test:test -X POST -d "<query>for $e in /musicCollection/entry return <entry> {$e/Type} {$e/Name} {$e/Artist} </entry></query>" "http://localhost:123/rest/music"
```

i got:

```
Stopped at D:/Programs/BaseX/webapp, 1/1:
[XPST0003] Empty query.
```

with this:

```
curl -u test:test -X POST -d "<query><text>for $e in /musicCollection/entry return <entry> {$e/Type} {$e/Name} {$e/Artist} </entry></text></query>" "http://localhost:123/rest/music"
```

i got this error:

```
Stopped at D:/Programs/BaseX/webapp, 1/41:
[XPST0003] Expecting return value.
```

What is the correct way to send this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last attempt to send the query with the POST method was pretty close: If your XQuery string includes angle brackets or XML entities, you’ll need to use [CDATA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) to prevent your query characters from being interpreted as XML:

```
curl
  -u test:test
  -X POST
  -d "<query><text><![CDATA[for $e in /musicCollection/entry return <entry> {$e/Type} {$e/Name} {$e/Artist} </entry>]]></text></query>"
  "http://localhost:123/rest/music"
```

The CDATA section is not required if your query string is unambiguous:

```
curl
  -u test:test
  -X POST
  -d "<query><text>/musicCollection/entry/(element entry {Type,Name,Artist})</text></query>"
  "http://localhost:123/rest/music"
```